# PC DOS E Editor (3.13v): "Not enough memory" error with a file of 1.65 MB and 40 320 lines, even with the /S switch

Tags: ibm, editor, pc, pc-dos

Using the E editor included with IBM PC DOS 7, I can't open a particular plain text file without encountering a "Not enough memory" error.  The editor was invoked with the `/S` switch to make it handle large files (i.e. `E.EXE /S FOO.TXT`), and E hasn't had problems opening others, both larger and smaller than this one.  The [file in question](https://uploadnow.io/f/D5yBggH) has 40320 lines and 1572480 characters, and can be generated by a simple program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

words = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight')

def permuts(items):
    if len(items) < 2:
        yield tuple(items)
        return

    for i in range(0, len(items)):
        for rest in permuts((*items[:i], *items[i+1:])):
            yield items[i], *rest

for p in permuts(words):
    print(' '.join(p), end='\r\n')
```

Note: PC DOS 2000 (it also has E 3.13v) was also tried with the same result.  None of the other editors tested, be it MELite (DOS, same configuration), Notepad (Windows) or vi (Linux), has any problem opening or editing this file as plain text.  Perhaps someone can shed some light on why E is encountering difficulty with this specific example?  In case it's relevant, testing was conducted with PC DOS 7 virtual machines, in both VirtualBox and VMware formats.

Comment: You might want to add a bit of additional information. Like if you tried other files of same or larger size? It doesn't sound like a safe idea to try some random file from the net.

Comment: As stated in the original post: "...E hasn't had problems opening others, both larger and smaller than this one..."

Comment: It might not like so many lines (40320).

Comment: Attempts to infiltrate never count on careful users but the ones eager to download and test, don't they?

Comment: "It might not like so many lines (40320)." Even though I've opened larger files, it didn't occur to me the number of lines might be affecting the editor. When I get back to DOS on Monday, I'll modify the file by joining lines and see if that makes a difference and report the outcome. Either way, thanks very much for the suggestion since I hadn't thought of it :)

Comment: "Attempts to infiltrate never count on careful users but the ones eager to download and test, don't they?" Yes, they do. In this case, though, I can trace the provenience of the file back to the very machine from which it emitted. I guess I took that fact for granted. I apologize if I came off as dismissive of your (valid) point. I certainly did not mean it that way.

Comment: I would be less concerned about the file itself than about some shady file-upload website I never heard of that requires me to enable JavaScript for no good reason.

Comment: You may find that the maximum number of lines is around 2^15.

Comment: @user3840170: I'll be sure not to reference such sites in the future. I'm not a fan of mandatory JavaScript, either. Thanks.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Mine seems to accept a maximum of 16293 lines without issue. It did load a file of 16294 lines, but with a "Not enough memory" message still displayed in the status bar. Anything larger than that, it goes back to not loading the file at all.

Comment: @Brian It did manage a file of up to 16293 lines. This looks like a small number given MS-DOS Edit (which has no large file capability) is reputed to handle up to over 65000 lines...

Comment: Four bytes pr line in a 64 kb segment and some initial house keeping.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: It adds up. Just curious, but are those four bytes per line used to contain status information, or something else?

Comment: Four bytes per line sounds very much like it could be a file offset (for up-to-4G files), so you could relatively quickly seek to the start of any given line. Had you the source code, you could store the offset of lines 11, 21, 31, etc, and increase the file size capacity (in terms of line count) tenfold. Of course, looking for line 33, you would then have to seek to line 31 and read, counting newlines. Depends on whether you'd rather have slightly slower but larger files. Or, I could be wrong, my wife and kids will confirm that happens occasionally :-)

Comment: I would expect this to be a segment:offset pair for the memory location holding the string corresponding to the line in the file.  All this is just guessing without access to the source code or spending time with a debugger.

Comment: I believe the only editor that is both actively maintained and has a dos port is vim.

Comment: I consider the original comment by @Brian to be an explanation of the issue I described in the title. (I can't find a better way to mark this thread as answered, so if a mod can do it while crediting Brian, please feel free.)
And much thanks to Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen & paxdiablo for your inputs!

Comment: Either you or Brian need to post an answer quoting (and maybe expanding upon) the details in the comment. Then you need to mark *that* answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Brian Can you post an answer / edit the self-answer, please? Then it can be properly accepted.

Comment: Given that you did considerable investigation work, I think saying "following up on a suggestion from [Brian](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/7629/brian)" and then describing your results in this answer would be appropriate. Once an answer contains all the information (i.e., is self-contained), you can accept it using the relevant voting button on the left.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Was more an observation than an answer.

Comment: Ok, vim has outgrown MS-DOS.   I would suggest looking at the editor shipping with FreeDOS as it probably is the only one left somebody cares about maintaining.   Looks like it is written using Turbo Vision - https://opensource.com/article/21/6/freedos-text-editor

Answer (score 1):

MS-DOS edit also had trouble with text files as small as a few hundred KB in my experience.

When you think about the technical problems involved, and the difficulty of memory management in DOS it's not at all surprising that there would be problems editing a file that has trouble fitting entirely into the lower memory area with the executable.

And even when it does there are often performance issues later into the file.

When I read old Project Gutenberg texts in DOS I had to use a program that was explicitly a reader so it could reasonably assume it only needed about a screen of the file loaded at a time. (In my case this was integrated in QuickFiler, the MC clone I had on every system)

This works with MELite specifically because the program was designed to make it possible. And with Notepad because Windows has better memory management (and might also have code specifically for this).